# attempting to override startHandshake for SSLSocket for use with Axis2

Tags: java, http, ssl, apache-axis

I'm working on a project that is connecting to a server expecting a clear text [PROXY protocol](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) line before the SSL handshake.  The server side requires the line to be present and won't correctly handshake without it.  To avoid having another piece of software between the client and server (like haproxy) I've opted to try to extend the javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket class (and the SSLProtocolSocketFactory class).  I've been able to verify that my class is the one getting created and accessed.  It's a slightly modified version of [this class](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/src/java/org/apache/commons/ssl/SSLSocketWrapper.java) (SSLSocketWrapper).

The problem I'm running in to now, is that the startHandshake method present in javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket is seemingly not called.  I've tried debug breakpoints and they don't even trigger for startHandshake.  I've been suspending the process and stepping around with the debugger for a while and I can see that when Axis2 goes to send the request the HTTP classes are definitely using my Socket class.

I'm wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely with trying to override startHandshake.  Perhaps I'm re-inventing the wheel (though I haven't found anyone else doing this yet).  Any help would be appreciated

Here's the code for the factory:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory;

public class ProxyProtoSSLProtocolSocketFactory extends
SSLProtocolSocketFactory {

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
        boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return new ProxySSLSocketWrapper((SSLSocket) super.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2,
        int arg3, HttpConnectionParams arg4) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ProxySSLSocketWrapper((SSLSocket)super.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress clientHost,
        int clientPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ProxySSLSocketWrapper((SSLSocket) super.createSocket(host, port, clientHost, clientPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {
    return new ProxySSLSocketWrapper((SSLSocket) super.createSocket(host, port));
}
}
```

Here are the parts I've changed from the SSLSocketWrapper class linked above.  I'm just posting the portion I've changed since it's nearly 385 lines, a bit much for inline.  At this point it's virtually nothing different from the one above, and I have just been putting in a breakpoint in startHandshake as a sanity check that it hasn't been called.

```
public class ProxySSLSocketWrapper extends SSLSocket {
private SSLSocket s;

public ProxySSLSocketWrapper(SSLSocket s) {
    this.s = s;
}

/* javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket */

/**
 * Start handshake after sending over PROXY protocol line.
 */
@Override
public void startHandshake() throws IOException {
  s.startHandshake();
  /*
   if (s instanceof SSLSocket) {
     InetAddress dest = s.getInetAddress();
     InetAddress local = s.getLocalAddress();
     int localPort = s.getLocalPort();
     int destPort = s.getPort();
     String proxyLine = String.format("PROXY TCP4 %s %s %d %d\r\n", local.getHostAddress(), dest.getHostAddress(), localPort, destPort);
     System.err.print("Proxy line written: " + proxyLine);
     System.err.flush();
     OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
     OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
     writer.write(proxyLine);
     writer.flush();
       ((SSLSocket) s).startHandshake();
   }
   */
```

}

The attempted invocation of the connection is just trying to make a SOAP call via Axis2 generated stubs.

Comment: Can we see some examples of what you are currently trying?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work anyway, as the nested `SSLSocket` will encrypt the `PROXY TCP4` request.

You need a *plaintext* socket, with a `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket` wrapped around it, and your proxy SSL socket wrapped around that.

I would wrap the plaintext socket as well, override getOutputStream(), and send the `PROXY TCP4` line on the first output.

Comment: I guess I was under the impression that the SSLSocket wouldn't encrypt the request if it went out ahead of the handshake.  If I have ProxySSLSocket(SSLSocket(plaintext))) wouldn't getOutputStream still get encrypted?  Or am I mis-understanding the idea here?

Comment: `SSLSocket` will *start* the handhshake on the first I/O, but not necessarily by calling `startHandshake()` itself. The output stream of the plaintext socket can't get encrypted.